# const vs static NSStrings in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

These lines are both in the implementation file above the `@implementation` declaration.

```
NSString * const aVar = @"aVarStringValue";

static NSString *aVar = @"aVarStringValue";
```

As far as I understand, the second `static` is allocated once only within the lifetime of the application and this fact contributes to performance.

But does this mean it is essentially a memory leak seeing as that block of memory will never be released?

And does the first `const` declaration get allocated every time it is accessed in contrast?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`static` keyword in Objective-C (and C/C++) indicates the visibility of the variable.  A static variable (not in a method) may only be accessed within that particular `.m` file.  A static local variable on the other hand, gets allocated only once.

`const` on the other hand, indicates that the reference may not be modified and/or reassigned; and is orthogonal on how it can be created (compilers may optimize consts though).

It's worth mentioning that `NSString` literals get initialized and never get destroyed in the life of application.  They are allocated in a read-only part of the memory.

Comment: Wish I could give you a tick, but bbum was first.

Comment: @firstresponder - No bbum wasn't? notnoop answered an entire day before bbum (in EST, anyways. He answered one minute earlier on the same day in other time zones.)

Comment: @notnoop Any reference source for this answer?

Answer (score 49):

The *static* only changes the scope of the variable, not how it is declared or stored.

In both cases, the compiler will create a constant version of the NSString instance that is stored in the mach-o file.   Thus, there is only ever one instance of either (note that you can change the behavior to cause the string to be dynamically created on load of the mach-o, but there is still just one instance).

The `static` just marks the `aVar` variable as being visible within the scope of the compilation unit -- the file -- only.   Without the `static`, you could redeclare the string as `extern NSString *aVar;` in a header somewhere and have access to it from anywhere.

The `const` is orthogonal and, in the case of of NSString reference is pretty much entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks.  This bit: 'you could redeclare the string as extern NSString *aVar; in a header somewhere and have access to it from anywhere' really drove it home for me.

Comment: Actually the `const` is not entirely irrelevent--it prevents you from changing `aVar` to point to a different NSString object.

Comment: Actually `static` also indicate how variable is stored. It stands the whole lifetime of the program.

Answer (score 6):

In order to resolve all possible discussions on need of `static` and position of `const`:

According to C99/GNU99 specification (which usually used for Objective-C code):

- `static`

  - is storage-class specifier
  - objects of file level scope by default has **external** linkage
  - objects of file level scope with static specifier has **internal** linkage
- `const`

  - is type-qualifier (is a part of type)
  - keyword applied to immediate left instance - i.e.

    - `MyObj const * myVar;` - unqualified pointer to const qualified object type
    - `MyObj * const myVar;` - const qualified pointer to unqualified object type
  - Leftmost usage - applied to the object type, not variable

    - `const MyObj * myVar;` - unqualified pointer to const qualified object type

**THUS:**

`static NSString * const myVar;` - constant pointer to immutable string with internal linkage.

Absence of the `static` keyword will make variable name global and might lead to name conflicts within the application.

Comment: I've just recently worked with Objective-C code that declares all local variables like this `NSMutableArray * const myArray = [NSMutableArray new];`. I've never used `const` for that and now I'm confused if I have been doing it wrong all the time ?

Comment: Note that this is *only* true when static is used in a global, file-level context.  Within the body of a method, the meaning is entirely different, and means that the storage is allocated once in the data segment of the file, rather than being stored on the stack or heap, and is shared across invocations of that method.